# Save a result from a mongodb query into an array or list

Tags: javascript

Here my problems. I have a collection namend "Employee" and a key named "25".

I need to save result of my query in to an array or list. I tried my code bellow but it not working.

```
var arr = [];
mongodb.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/data', function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var test = db.collection('Employee');
      test.find({ "Age": "25" }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                  //console.log(data);
                var arr = data;
    });
                console.log(arr);
```

I tried `console.log(data)` and got result

```
[ { email: 'example@email.com' } ]
```

But `console.log(arr)` it only show a null array `[]`

How I can save a result from a mongodb query into an array or list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're redeclaring `arr` in your callback function. Change:

```
var arr = data;
```

For:

```
arr = data
```

Also, put your `console.log(arr)` just after the above line or you'll only get an empty array (you're logging `arr` before the asynchronous operation has finished).

#### Update:

Added multiple queries in a loop.

```
const getEmployees = (collection, age) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    collection.find({ "Age": age.toString() }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray((err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(data)
    });
  })
)

mongodb.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/data', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var promises = []
  for (let age = 0; age < 60; age+= 5) {
    promises.push(getEmployees(db.collection('Employee'), age))
  }
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: It not different with `console.log(data)`
I will put my query on `for` loop so I need store my result on an array or a list txt file.

Comment: If you are going to make several querys in parallel I would 'promisify' the calls and wrap them on `Promise.all()`. See edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks you. Hope you fine.

Answer (score -2):

In your code, you define your variable "arr" in the return function, so you cant access it outside, Try replace your code with this :

```
var arr = [];
mongodb.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/data', function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var test = db.collection('Employee');
      test.find({ "Age": "25" }, {"email": 1, "_id": 0}).toArray(function (err,data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                  //console.log(data);
                this.arr = data;
    });
                console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that making the database query is asynchronous.

Comment: Hum no... Db driver make asynchronous query. the problem is the double declaration of variable "arr"

Comment: That's a problem *as well*. `mongodb.connect` and `toArray` are still asynchronous.